# OS X Yosemite youtrack proxy without modifying url

Tags: apache, osx-yosemite, youtrack

I'm setting up the standalone version of youtrack on OS X Yosemite. It is currently running on local-ip:8080 using the following command:

```
sudo -u youtrack java -jar youtrack.jar local-ip:8080
```

Preferably I'd like to be able to access it via www.domain.com/youtrack.

I've attempted to use the OS X internal apache server to act as a proxy to the you track server (which comes with its own web server) by:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyStatus On

ProxyPass /youtrack http://local-ip:8080
ProxyPassReverse /youtrack http://local-ip:8080
```

However this does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using YouTrack 6, you can archive it without a proxy with the following start command:

```
sudo -u youtrack java -jar youtrack.jar local-ip:8080/youtrack
```

Full syntax is described here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD6/Installing+YouTrack+with+JAR+Distribution